# Group a file's contents by two fields and sum a third field

Tags: awk

I have a file below where I want to sum up the third field and count, based on a group 1st and 2nd fields.

File

```
 AAA~111~2
 BBB~111~2
 AAA~111~1
 AAA~111~3
 AAA~222~2
```

Expected Output

```
 AAA~111~6~3
 BBB~111~2~1
 AAA~222~2~1
```

So far, I have this code that only sums up the 3rd column

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="~"}{arr[$1,$2]+=$3 }END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' File
```

Comment: Don't you just need a second array for the counts? `c[$1,$2]++` then `print i,arr[i],c[i]` at the `END`

Comment: FYI there's also [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), which provides a nice expressive way to do stuff like this: `datamash -t~ groupby 1,2 sum 3 count 3 < File`

Answer (score 3):

You just have to keep track of the count in the same way as you keep track of the sum:

```bash
$ awk -F'~' 'BEGIN { SUBSEP = OFS = FS } { s[$1,$2] += $3; ++c[$1,$2] } END { for (i in s) { print i, s[i], c[i] } }' file
AAA~111~6~3
BBB~111~2~1
AAA~222~2~1
```

---

You could also choose a tool like GNU `datamash`, which knows how to calculate basic things like sums etc. on data in simple record formats:

```bash
$ datamash -t '~' -s groupby 1,2 sum 3 count 3 <file
AAA~111~6~3
AAA~222~2~1
BBB~111~2~1
```

Here, `datamash` is asked to treat the input as tilde-delimited fields in line-based records.  It groups the data on the first two fields while adding two new fields consisting of the sum of the 3rd field from all records in each group and the number of records in each group.

If the input data is sorted on the first two fields, you may remove the `-s` option.